# Clip the contour with polygon using ggplot and R

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

I want to create a contour and then clip the contour by the polygon and only show the contour within the polygon.

**Shapefile data can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ztvmibsslr9ocmc/YOtiwB8p9p)**

**Csv file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mg2bo4rcr6n3dks/temp.csv)**

The code I used is as follows:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("rgdal")
library("gpclib")
library("maptools")
require(sp) 

age2100 <- read.csv("temp.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",")
shape.dir <- "C:/Users/jdbaba/Documents/R working folder/shape" # use your directory name here

lon.shape <- readOGR(shape.dir, layer = "Export_Output_4")
str(lon.shape)

lon.df <- fortify(lon.shape, region = "Id")
p <- ggplot(lon.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
    geom_polygon(colour = "black", fill = "grey80", size = 1) +
    theme() 

p <- p + geom_point(data=age2100,aes(x=age2100$x,y=age2100$y,group="z"),size=0.1)
p <- p + geom_density2d(colour="red")
p
```

Here, I have created the map, points and the contour. I don't know whether the code I am using created the contour for variable z or not. If it is not correct can anyone suggest me ?

The sample output that I got is as follows:

[image]

Now, I want to clip the contour within the polygon and hide the part of contour that is outside the polygon.

I want to know how to add the labels to the contour and control the contour interval.

Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Thanks

Jdbaba

Comment: That has nothing to do with the plot. I was just testing that. I will delete that. Thanks.

Comment: @Arun it works for me. maybe you need to call `gpclibPermit()` once in the session.

Comment: @Arun yes this works for me and the graph above is the output from the code I have written. Thanks.

Comment: This contour plot IGNORES the 'z' value of your `age2100` points data frame. The contour is based purely on the locations. It is using a two-dimensional kernel smoothing computed by the kde2d function from the MASS package. If you are trying to produce a smooth map of the z values then you need to look into geostatistics and clipping contours to a polygon is now the least of your problems.

Comment: @Spacedman you are right. Do you know how can I plot the z values on the plot above. I tried to do that but I always get error. The commone error I get is " increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected". Can I create the plot with z values with discrete data ?

Comment: Your data is a set of irregularly spaced x,y,z triples. To do any smoothing you are trying to say something about the value of z where you don't have an (x,y) point, and that depends on your belief in the model behind the data. That's geostatistics in a nut-shell. Go get a book on geostatistics or kriging, read the Spatial Task View on CRAN then get back to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce your map exactly. The code you provided gives me a map with two sets of contours - one that looks like yours and one that overlaps it in the southern part of the region. I suspect this is an artefact of your `group` setting. Also, I can see there is an island in the southern part of what I assume is the lake.

[image]

I like to clean up and partition my ggplot stuff into bits, since I often find something in an early part of a ggplot call confuses something in a later part. Here's how I would map the region, draw points, and then add a density contour:

```
map <- function(){
  geom_polygon(data=lon.df,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=piece),colour="black",fill="grey80",size=1)
}

points <- function(){
  geom_point(data=age2100,aes(x=x,y=y),size=0.1)
}

density <- function(){
  geom_density2d(data=age2100,aes(x=x,y=y),colour="red")
}

ggplot()+map() +points() +density()
```

Which gives this:

[image]

Now that's much different to what your contour looks like, and I don't know why. Maybe your group parameter is grouping all the points with the same z?

Anyway, it seems you don't want a density plot, you want a map of your Z values over your area. This is going to need kriging or some other interpolation technique. Forget about ggplot for a while, concentrate on the numbers.

For starters, plot the points coloured by the z value. You should see this:

[image]

which at least will give you a good idea of what the correct contour will look like.

Anyway, this is getting into a full-on tutorial..

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed explanation. I liked the point plot you created. Could you please put the code that you used to create that plot ? I created the point plots with z on color. But I cannot get the plot similar to what you created. That looks really nice and thanks a lot.

Comment: Make your points into a SpatialPointsDataFrame and use `spplot`, but I don't like that colour scheme so I used `automapPlot` from package `autoMap`. That package can also do the smoothing you may need...

Comment: Hi Spacedman, thank you for your reply. I really appreciate your help. But since I am new to both spplot and automaplot I would like to request you to provide the code you used to create the plot. I tried to dig in to those packages for last hour or so and tried to create what you did but I was unable to do so. I have a presentation to give today after couple of hours so your code will be good for today. I will spend more time afterwards on spplot and automaplot to have a better understanding. Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: Find some more general help on R and spatial data, or ask some new simpler questions on SO, and we'll be pleased to answer them. They don't belong attached to this question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. As I am digging through I created some piece of code that is helpful to create the map. library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

data <- read.table("temp.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)
data
str(data)

coordinates(data)=~x+y
str(data)

spplot(data)

Comment: I was able to reproduce the exact graph with the following command :   p1 <- automapPlot(data1,auto.key=F)
p1