# R ggplot2 stat_density2d grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

In R, ggplot2, How can I change the grid used in the `stat_density2d` geometry object to be constrained by a triangular region?

I am plotting ternary diagrams which are not standard ggplot2 types, the contours are spilling out over the axes. The code for the actual ternary diagram is quite lengthy, but in essence, I need to constrain the contours to be bound by an equilateral triangle.

Here is sample code to reproduce the issue:

```
library(ggplot2)

triangle <- data.frame(x=c(0,.5,1),y=c(0,1,0))
dummy <- data.frame(x=c(0.25,0.50,0.75),y=c(0.25,0.75,0.25))

p <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=triangle,aes(x,y),fill="transparent",color="black",size=1)
p <- p + geom_point(data=dummy,aes(x,y))
p <- p + stat_density2d(data=dummy,aes(x,y)) + theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.border = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())
p
```

[image: Sample]

I believe it is due to the grid being associated with the original cartesian coordinate bounds for the plotting area, to demonstrate, consider the below code:

```
library(ggplot2)

triangle <- data.frame(x=c(0,.5,1),y=c(0,1,0))
dummy <- data.frame(x=c(0.25,0.50,0.75),y=c(0.25,0.75,0.25))

p <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=triangle,aes(x,y),fill="transparent",color="black",size=1)
p <- p + geom_point(data=dummy,aes(x,y))
p <- p + stat_density2d(data=dummy,aes(x,y),geom='tile',contour=F,fill="transparent",color="magenta") + theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.border = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())
p
```

Which produces the following:

[image: Sample2]

So how can I change the grid to be bound by the triangle. and not by the original Cartesian plotting bounds?

Comment: Feed the density layer only the points within the triangle...? Can't help much more than that without an example to work with.

Comment: I'll put together something a MWE to demonstrate.

Comment: Not an answer to your exact question, but have you checked out the [ternvis package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ternvis/index.html)? I am guessing that it would be more convenient.

Comment: @nograpes, thanks, but I would like to stick with ggplot2, for consistency across all of my work...

Comment: Well, maybe you would be interested in [this page](http://srmulcahy.github.io/2012/12/04/ternary-plots-r.html) which describes one solution in `ggplot2`.

Comment: I have extended much of that code, it was the original source that I used, however, it still doesn't resolve the issue of being able to use stat_density2d.

Comment: Solved it. I ended up using stat_contour. After the object was created, I set the values of the grid to '0' for all the points qualified as lying outside of the triangle perimeter, using `point.in.polygon` command from the `sp` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since publishing the [ggtern](http://www.ggtern.com) package, this is the result which can now be achieved using the following simple code:

```
#load the library
library(ggtern)

#Create dummy data
df <- data.frame(T=c(.8,.1,.1),
                 L=c(.1,.8,.1),
                 R=c(.1,.1,.8))

#Now plot the diagram
ggtern(data=df,aes(y=T,x=L,z=R)) + geom_point() + geom_density2d() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This would be a somewhat crude option, only partially demonstrated here:

```
d1 <- data.frame(x = c(0,0.5,0),y = c(0,1,1))
p + geom_polygon(data = d1,aes(x = x,y = y),fill = "white",colour = "black")
```

There are some other ideas you might investigate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14393172/324364) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14373284/324364) although I think they might involve dropping ggplot2.

In theory you could do something fancy using `grid.path`, but the difficulty there (as always) is moving between the device and plot coordinate systems cleanly.